# When I try to install a .deb file it takes me to Ubuntu Software Center and doesn't install

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, deb

I've downloaded the `.deb` file of the Brackets editor and tried to install it. It takes me to the Ubuntu Software Centre to install the file, then after the installation completes it shows the <kbd>Install</kbd> button, instead of showing the <kbd>Launch</kbd> and <kbd>Remove</kbd> buttons.

This happens every time I try to install a `.deb` file.

I'm running the latest Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS update.

Comment: Try to install from command line using `dpkg -i file.deb`.

Comment: Did you double click on it or you used the don't install command.

Comment: install gdebi and associate it with deb files

Comment: Try installing the pakcage using the command line: sudo dpkg -i <debfile>, This will eventually provide error messages that hint on what might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gdebi is the best gui tool out there.

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

---

I don't use Gdebi wright now because I'm in Kubuntu and avoid gtk apps. What I do is use the file `~/.local/share/applications/install_deb_term.desktop` with the lines

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Install in terminal with apt
Comment=Install deb files in terminal with apt
Exec=sudo apt install %f
Icon=gdebi
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;System;
```

then select the deb file, "Open with" and select "Install in terminal"...

Comment: The desktop file I use is a bit different, more kde-specific. I use `Terminal=false` and `Exec=konsole --hold -e sudo apt install %f` to keep the terminal open after finish. In gnome-terminal you need a new profile set to keep window open and the line `Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME -e 'sudo apt install %f'`.